# how to stop airflow scheduled dag

Tags: python, airflow

I accidentally scheduled a simple DAG job to run every 5 minutes.
I typed below command:

```
airflow backfill jobs -s 2017-05-01 -e 2017-06-07
```

I can see airflow Webserver GUI, it launched many backfilled jobs.
I tried to mark the running jobs as "succeeded", but it returns errors.

I want to run every day instead of every 5 minutes.
How can I stop the wrong job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change the schedule or start date of a dag it's best to rename it as well.

To stop the old dag, pause it in the UI by moving the ON button:

[image]

To OFF.

Comment: thanks! what is the way to remove the DAG record from the UI?

Comment: There isn't a super nice way of doing that yet sadly... Generally you have to go into the airflow DB and delete the dag from the dag table.